# Git repository clone failed. Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected

Tags: eclipse, bitbucket, clone, git-clone

Git repository clone failed.
Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which JGit/EGit version? Are you up to date?